# Static parameters don't get applied

Tags: c#, .net, ncalc

I recently tried [nCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/) for parsing formula from strings. But when I tried static parameters I always ended with `null` as a result. Here is the example I tried:

```
Expression e = new Expression("[bProd] + [bUp]");

e.Parameters["bProd"] = 50;
e.Parameters["bUp"] = 60;

var res = e.Evaluate();
```

Where `res` is always null. The [nCalc Doc about static](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=parameters&referringTitle=Home) didn't helped me. Can anyone point me to the problem? I am using the latest version of `nCalc` included using `nuget`.

Comment: I copy-pasted your code to the empty console project and I've got 110 as a result. Can you do the same thing?

Comment: @astef Yes. I simplified it for this question and the only problem was type casting, meaning the numbers (50,60) where interpreted as strings (I used `var`) Now that I changed them to integer all worked fine! Even if that makes no sense for me it was the only change I applied. Thanks!